# How write a procedure to drop all partitions older than 12 months?

Tags: oracle

I have a table with partition based on date field. Now, I have to write a procedure to drop all partitions older than 12 months.

I have the entries in the user_tab_partitions table in the following format.

```
PARTITION_NAME      HIGH_VALUE
--------------      ----------
SYS_P28468650       20161221
SYS_P28468649       20161220
SYS_P28468648       20161219
SYS_P28468647       20161218
```

Kindly help me on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like partitions are based on number, not DATE values.

Anyway, procedure like this should work:

```
DECLARE

    HighValue NUMBER;

    CURSOR TabPartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_POSITION;

BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TabPartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT HighValue;
        IF TO_DATE(HighValue, 'YYYYMMDD') < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
        END IF;     
    END LOOP;

END;
```

You can also use

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE DROP PARTITION FOR ('||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||') UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
```

Comment: Thankyou for the rply                                                                        
 Error at line 1
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at "SYS.STANDARD", line 167
ORA-06512: at line 11

Comment: Is is working now? If not , what is the data type of partition key? According to your sample it appears to be `NUMBER`. Is it `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: the partition key is in NUMBER(38) datatype and in following  YYYYMMDD format.